# Row to Column transformation without Aggregate function in SQL

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

Folks, Below is the sample table that I have..

***Current Table***

```
PropertyAttributeValueID PropertyTypeID PropertyAttributeName PropertyAttributeValue
1000                     3216           Mileage               20.4
1000                     3216           Engine                DIESEL
1000                     3216           Manufacturer          HONDA
1000                     3216           Seat_Capacity         5
1001                     3216           Mileage               19.2
1001                     3216           Engine                PETROL
1001                     3216           Manufacturer          SUZUKI
1001                     3216           Seat_Capacity         4
1002                     3216           Mileage               18.0
1002                     3216           Engine                DIESEL
1002                     3216           Manufacturer          SUZUKI
1002                     3216           Seat_Capacity         4
1003                     3216           Mileage               16.3
1003                     3216           Engine                PETROL
1003                     3216           Manufacturer          HYUNDAI
1003                     3216           Seat_Capacity         5
```

I need to create this table from the above one

***Desired Table***

```
PropertyAttributeValueID Mileage Engine Manufacturer Seat_Capacity
1000                     20.4    DIESEL HONDA        5
1001                     19.2    PETROL SUZUKI       4
1002                     18.0    DIESEL SUZUKI       4
1003                     16.3    PETROL HYUNDAI      5
```

I thought of using pivot, but As you can see, there's no aggregate function needed, How do I create it?

Comment: Only ever 4 propertytypeattributeid ?

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer close to your requirement if you include sample data as text in the question rather than a linked image, same with desired output.

Comment: Yes, there are few more but I'm trying to start with these..

Comment: @P.Salmon, Done..

Comment: EAV is a messy schema pattern.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you for responding, do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use inner join

```
select a.PropertyAttributeValueID 
        , a.PropertyAttributeValue  as Mileage
        , b.PropertyAttributeValue  as Engine
        , c.PropertyAttributeValue  as Manufacturer       
        , d.PropertyAttributeValue  as Seat_Capacity          
from my_table a 
inner join my_table b on a.PropertyAttributeValueID = b.PropertyAttributeValueID 
        and a.PropertyAttributeName='Mileage'
            and b.PropertyAttributeName = 'Engine'
inner join my_table c on a.PropertyAttributeValueID = c.PropertyAttributeValueID 
        and c.PropertyAttributeName='Manufacturer'
inner join my_table d on a.PropertyAttributeValueID = d.PropertyAttributeValueID 
        and d.PropertyAttributeName='Seat_Capacity'
```

for better performance you could add a composite index on the table

```
create index  my_idx on my_table ( PropertyAttributeName
                , PropertyAttributeValueID 
               , PropertyAttributeValue);
```

Comment: Please explain these two: `PropertyAttributeValueID` and `PropertyTypeID`.  Normally, you don't need both.

Comment: @RickJames  explain better your comment  ..  you are referring to the composite index ?

Comment: @harishgupta - Neither one seems to be the `PRIMARY KEY`, or is it?  What is a "Type"?  Maybe the Entity that has these attributes?

Comment: @RickJames  . if you are refferrng  to the composite index  .. in left side there are the columns involved  in where clause and at the right the columns involved  in select clause for the table  .. in this way  all the values (for the indexed  table) in the query are found directly in  the index  avoindening the access to the data store in the table

Comment: @RickJames PropertyAttributeValueID is more like the objectID whereas PropertyTypeID tells you what type of Property does the respective ObjectID belong to..
'PropertyAttributeValueID PropertyTypeID PropertyTypeName
1                                       1                        building   
2                                       2                        Vehicle     
3                                       2                        Vehicle
4                                       1                        building'